# Flutter fill DropdownMenuItem from list

Tags: flutter, dart

My list contain id and name.

```
List myList = [];

for(var i = 0; i< myList.length; i++) {
        print("${myList[i].id}" + ' ' + "${myList[i].name}");
}
```

In console get:

I/flutter ( 7412): 10 ACCOUNTING

I/flutter ( 7412): 20 RESEARCH

I/flutter ( 7412): 30 SALES

I/flutter ( 7412): 40 OPERATIONS

When try populate DropdownMenuItem

```
items: myList.map((item) {
return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value: item["id"].toString(),
  child: new Text(
    item["name"],
  ),
);
}).toList(),
```

Get error:

Class 'Dept' has no instance method '[]'.

Receiver: Instance of 'Dept'

Tried calling: [ ](" id ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming myList is of type Dept

```
items: myList.map((item) {
    return new DropdownMenuItem<Dept>(
      value: item.id,
      child: new Text(
        item.name,
      ),
    );
    }).toList(),
```

Comment: Thanks for help, In my solution instead return new DropdownMenuItem<Dept>   use return new DropdownMenuItem<String>  and work fine.  In my example I'm change  value: item["id"].toString(),     to     value: item.id